# Expressing the PDF as an integral

Tags: probability, density-function

*If U and V are independent normal random variables, each having mean 0 and
variance 1, and if $$W={U\over V}$$ 
Use a conditioning argument, or otherwise, so that for any $w ∈  \mathbb{R}$ express the
quantity $F_W (w) =  \mathbb{P} [W ≤ w]$ as an integral.*

Would I be correct with the solution $F_W (w) =  \mathbb{P} [W ≤ w] = \int_0^1{F_V (wv)dv}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F_W(w)=\mathbb P[W<w]=\iint_{u/v\le w}f_U(u)f_V(v)\,du\,dv$$
The inequality $u/v\le w$ is equivalent to $u\ge vw$ for $v<0$ and to $u\le vw$ for $v>0$. Split outer integral into two integrals: $$\tag{*}\label{*}F_W(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int^{\infty}_{vw}f_U(u)f_V(v)\,du\,dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{vw}f_U(u)f_V(v)\, du \,dv$$
$$F_W(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}(1-F_U(vw))f_V(v)\,dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}F_U(vw)f_V(v)\, dv$$
We then can use the symmetry of standard normal distribution $F_U(x)=1-F_U(-x)$ and rewrite
$$F_W(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}F_U(-vw)f_V(v)\,dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}F_U(vw)f_V(v)\, dv$$
Replacement $-v=\nu$ in the first integral leads to
$$F_W(w)=\int^{\infty}_{0}F_U(\nu w)f_V(\nu)\,d\nu+\int_{0}^{\infty}F_U(vw)f_V(v)\, dv=2\int_{0}^{\infty}F_U(vw)f_V(v)\, dv$$

Let us also find pdf of $U/V$ in general case. Start with (\ref{*}) and change variables in both inner integrals: $u\mapsto t$ s.t. $u=tv$. Keep in mind that $v<0$ inside the first inner integral and $v>0$ in the second one.
$$F_W(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int^{-\infty}_{w}f_U(tv)f_V(v)v\,dt\,dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{w}f_U(tv)f_V(v)v\, dt \,dv=$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{-\infty}^{w}f_U(tv)f_V(v)|v|\,dt\,dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{w}f_U(tv)f_V(v)|v|\, dt \,dv = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{w}f_U(tv)f_V(v)|v|\, dt \,dv$$
Switch the order of integration by Tonelli theorem for non-negative functions and get 
$$F_W(w)= \int_{-\infty}^{w} \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_U(tv)f_V(v)|v|\, dv}_{f_{U/V}(t)} \,dt.$$

Comment: +1 for not letting me down and for working hard parallel...

Comment: @zoli Sorry for some duplicates: I'm new at MSE, and have not find your answer when opened this question today. Therefore I decided to write my own, and then it became a pity to delete it. Thank you!

Comment: I thank you (seriously) for warning me and not voting down.  : )

Comment: How would I (using the equation just before replacing $−v=\mathbf ν$) find the density function $f_W(w)$ in closed form? I've differentiated $$F_W(w)=\int_{-\infty}^0F_u(-wv)f_V(v)dv+\int_0^{\infty}F_u(wv)f_V(v)dv$$ with respect to $w$ to get $$f_W(w)=\int_{-\infty}^0-vf_u(-wv)f_V(v)dv+\int_0^{\infty}vf_u(wv)f_V(v)dv$$ but I don't know where to go from here to from here to find my closed form. Again any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @B.K97 Change variable in first integral now by $-v=\nu$ and use symmetry of pdf.

Comment: Have it now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, and using the independence

$$F_{\frac UV}(w)=P\left(\frac UV <w\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P\left(\frac Uv<w\ \mid\ V=v\right)f_V(v)dv=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P\left(\frac Uv<w\right)f_V(v)dv=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0}P\left(U>vw\right)f_V(v)dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(U<vw\right)f_V(v)dv=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0}(1-P\left(U\le vw\right))f_V(v)dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(U<vw\right)f_V(v)dv=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^0f_V(v)\ dv-\int_{-\infty}^{0}F_U(vw)f_V(v)dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}F_U(vw)f_V(v)dv=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^0f_V(v)\ dv-\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{-\infty}^{vw}f_U(x)\ dxf_V(v)dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{vw}f_U(x)\ dxf_V(v)dv.$$

In order to get the pdf of the ratio we take the derivative of the expression above with respect to $w$.

$$f_{\frac UV}(w)=\frac d{dw}F_{\frac UV}(w)=$$
$$=\frac d{dw}\left[-\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{-\infty}^{vw}f_U(x)\ dxf_V(v)dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{vw}f_U(x)\ dxf_V(v)dv\right]=$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac d{dw}\left[-\int_{-\infty}^{vw}f_U(x)\ dx\right]f_V(v)dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac d{dw}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{vw}f_U(x)\ dx\right]f_V(v)dv=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0}(-v)f_U(vw)f_V(v)dv+\int_{0}^{\infty}vf_U(vw)f_V(v)dv=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mid v\mid f_U(vw)f_V(v)dv.$$

... and this is independent from the normality of the distributions involved. The only restriction is that the pdf of $V$ exist. ($P(V=0)=0$ is important.)

If we take two independent standard normal variables then the integral to be evaluated [becomes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%7Cx%7C*e%5E(-A+x%5E2%2F2)+dx+from+-infinity+to+infinity)

$$f_{\frac UV}(w)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mid v\mid e^{-\frac12v^2(1+w^2)}\ dv=\frac1{\pi}\frac1{1+w^2}.$$
As it is known: the ratio distribution of two independent standard normal random variables is the simple form of the Cauchy distribution gained above.

Comment: How would I then find the density function of $W$ in closed form?

Comment: @B.K97 See, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution

Comment: @B.K97: and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution

Comment: In half of the cases $P(U/v < w)\neq F_U(wv)$.

Comment: @NCh: Oops, I am going to correct the negative part...

Answer (score 0):

You would need the double integral:
$$\iint_{u/v\le w}f_U(u)f_V(v)\text{d}(u,v)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{vw}^{\infty}f_U(u)f_V(v)\text{d}(u,v)+\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{vw}f_U(u)f_V(v)\text{d}(u,v)$$

Comment: $u/v<w$ does not imply $u<vw$, and for normal distributions especially.;

Comment: @NCh what do you mean? I am referring to the domain of integration.

Comment: Your equality is not true.

Comment: Does it not follow from $P(U/V\le w)=\iint_{u/v\le w} f_{U,V}(u,v)\mathrm d (u,v)$?

Comment: No. Solve inequality in the integral bound correctly.